# how to get output of a function in a class

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I defined a  model and then I have tried to fit the model on my dataset in pytrorch. it gives the below error. please clarify how to solve that

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'float'

```
class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size = (7,7), stride = (2,2), padding =(3,3), bias=False)
        self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 512, out_features = 1, bias = True)

        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight = torch.tensor([3]))

        self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy(task='binary')
        self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy(task='binary')

    def forward(self, data):
        pred = self.model(data)
        return pred
  
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch, batch_idx
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Train_Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Train ACC :", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

        return loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.training_step()).mean()
        self.log("training_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.training_step.clear()  # free memory

    def validation_step_outputs(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch, batch_idx
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Val Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Val ACC :", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.validation_step_outputs()).mean()
        self.log("validation_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.validation_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory


   def configure_optimizers(self):
       return [self.optimizer]
```

> 

it's for a PyTorch model for classification of x-ray images

Comment: `on_train_epoch_end` requires you to pass some value to the param `outs` see the function `def on_train_epoch_end(self, outs)` but you do not even use that param in the function so just remove it `def on_train_epoch_end(self)`

Comment: Make sure you call the method with the correct parameters. By the error, it seems that you don't pass `outs` to the argument. And it seems that you don't use the `outs` argument in the `on_train_epoch_end` function as well.

Comment: Thank you  It_is_Chris. I did what you said but it gives this error:    

TypeError: stack(): argument 'tensors' (position 1) must be tuple of Tensors, not method

Comment: @ashrafghaniafrah It appears you're not calling your functions. As the error indicates, `stack` takes tensors, not `methods`. Change the relevant lines to `epoch_average = torch.stack(self.training_step()).mean()` and `epoch_average = torch.stack(self.validation_step_outputs()).mean()`. Make sure that `out` is removed from the parameters of those functions as It_is_Chris described, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: @BrockBrown  I changed the code as you said. now it gives the new error. I updated the question.

Comment: @ashrafghaniafrah Would it be possible to provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If that's not possible, could you please provide the full error traceback instead of just the main part of the error?

Comment: You assigned `label` as `batch_idx`, which is probably an integer. That's why it throws an error saying `.float()` is not an attribute. My guess is that you used the wrong variable, as you typically want to call `.float()` on a tensor instead of the batch idx.